# PrismApplication not allowing Xamarin forms to initialize

Tags: xamarin, prism, uwp

I have a UWP, Xamarin forms sample from http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/xamarin-forms-uwp/

I am trying to add prism by changing the app to a PrismApplication and can't figure out how to call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e); before the app class constructor call.

I get a {"You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it."}.

Where can I call this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing because you haven't provided any code, but you don't have to do anything special to the UWP app.  Set the UWP app up like a normal Xamarin Forms application.  The only place you will modify is the Xamarin Forms PCL project.  To make it easy, just use the Prism Template Pack from the visual studio gallery.  Create a new Xamarin Forms Prism application and everything will be hooked up for you.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e7b6bde2-ba59-43dd-9d14-58409940ffa0

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I was trying to use PrismApplication in the UWP code not the portable code. So it was my misunderstanding causing the problem.  I was able to get a simple example working with the Prism Template pack.